# SQL Server Use parameters in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to use a parameter value inside a stored procedure. But for some reason I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near @sourceDB

The code I am writing is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[copyRecordType]
     (@loggedInUserID varchar(max), 
      @recordTypeID int, 
      @sourceDB varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
    WITH
    (
        TYPE=RDBMS,
        LOCATION=servername,--server name is not the issue
        DATABASE_NAME= @sourceDB,
        CREDENTIAL= AppCred--credential is also not the issue
    );
END
```

But if I hard code the value for `Database_Name` it works fine. For eg

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[copyRecordType]
    (@loggedInUserID varchar(max), 
     @recordTypeID int, 
     @sourceDB varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
    WITH
    (
        TYPE=RDBMS,
        LOCATION=servername,
        DATABASE_NAME= 'test',
        CREDENTIAL= AppCred
    );
END
```

Can someone guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

I am using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio. The database is on an Azure server.

Comment: Pretty sure you would have to use dynamic sql for this.

Comment: Most DDL can't be parametrised. Including this.

Comment: I would ask why you want to create an external data source inside a stored procedure in the first place. This will fail the second time it executes unless you also are dropping the data source.

Comment: @SeanLange it is to query a table in another database. I am going to drop the data source eventually

Comment: I understand what it would be used for. But why not simply create the external data source outside your procedure? Otherwise you either have to write a bunch of code to check if it exists or you have to constantly drop and recreate it. Seems kind of silly. Just create the external data source and leave it alone. Reference it when you need to.

Comment: @SeanLange ill do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Sean on this one, but one way that I'd think would work is to break it up into logical sections, if you don't have a lot of databases. Doesn't make sense to create and drop this over and over though. Just create it, and leave it there for when you need to use it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[copyRecordType](@loggedInUserID varchar(max), @recordTypeID int, @sourceDB  varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN

    IF(@sourceDB = 'db_1') 
    BEGIN
        CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
        WITH
        (
            TYPE=RDBMS,
            LOCATION=servername,--server name is not the issue
            DATABASE_NAME= db_1,
            CREDENTIAL= AppCred --credential is also not the issue
        );
    END
    IF(@sourceDB = 'db_2')
        BEGIN
        ...
        END
END
```

Comment: @SeanLange i think ill use dynamic sql rather than the code, as I have a lot of databases. Thanks anyways